# My app throws an acception error on launch_url when pressing on floating button

Tags: flutter

my app won't open the url when i press in the floating button

```
_launchURL(url) async {
        await launch(url);
    }
```

and the floating button:

```
onPressed: () {
    _launchURL("www.google.com");
},
```

when i press on the button:

```
: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method launch on channel plugins.flutter.io/url_launcher)
E/flutter ( 6856): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156:7)
E/flutter ( 6856): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6856): #1      MethodChannelUrlLauncher.launch.<anonymous closure> (package:url_launcher_platform_interface/method_channel_url_launcher.dart)
E/flutter ( 6856): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6856):
```

depedencies:

```
 url_launcher: ^6.0.2
```

import:

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
```

is there anything wrong with my code or something missing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you restart your app after adding the `url_launcher` dependency ?
If not, you should try to close your app, and make a `flutter clean`